# Yii2: Can ActiveQuery return array where the key is the first column of the SQL query?

Tags: php, database, activerecord, pdo, yii2

I often have a need for making a database query where the key of resulting array is the value of the first column specified in the SQL (instead of the key just being an auto-assigned incremental number as the array is being filled). Is that possible without having to rework the array manually afterwards?

I know there is `queryAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR)` but that only works for two colums (the array value is a single database column instead of a sub-array of all the remaining columns)

So, instead of:

```
array (
  0 => 
    array (
      'id' => 6955,
      'firstname' => 'John',
      'lastname' => 'Doe',
      'country' => 'United States',
    ),
  1 => 
    array (
      'id' => 8588,
      'firstname' => 'Helen',
      'lastname' => 'Smith',
      'country' => 'Denmark',
    ),
)
```

...I need:

```
array (
  6955 => array (
    'firstname' => 'John',
    'lastname' => 'Doe',
    'country' => 'United States',
  ),
  8588 => array (
    'firstname' => 'Helen',
    'lastname' => 'Smith',
    'country' => 'Denmark',
  ),
)
```

It doesn't necessarily have to be arrays - it could made of objects as well. It is just the structure that is important.

Comment: Could you give an example of expected result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `indexBy()` for this (it will not skip the chosen column in results but I think this is not a problem).

Example:

```
$query = (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->from('user')
    ->limit(10)
    ->indexBy('id')
    ->all();

returns [
    100 => ['id' => 100, 'username' => '...', ...], 
    101 => [...], 
    103 => [...], 
    ...
]
```

See [the guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html#indexing-query-results) for more info.